# Problem with Tapestry palette's arrow icons in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, stylesheet, opacity, tapestry

I'm using Tapestry to create pages for a web app, and have been using the palette component to add/delete items to/from a group.

The page looks great in Firefox (Tapestry seems biased towards Firefox), but my customers will all be using Internet Explorer (any versions from 6, 7, & 8) and in IE8, the disabled arrow buttons look awful.  In Firefox, they are faded, using an opacity setting of 25%, but this doesn't work in IE8 and instead you get a faded image with an ugly black border around the image.

In tapestry-core's stylesheet (default.css), you have the following for a disabled arrow button.

```
DIV.t-palette-controls BUTTON[disabled] IMG {
    filter: alpha(opacity = 25);
    -moz-opacity: .25;
}
```

These are clearly out of date, as -moz-opacity is no longer supported by Firefox (use opacity: 25 instead).  The problem is with filter: "alpha(opacity = 25);".  If I remove this, the arrows look fine in IE8, but they are not faded.

I got the magic instruction:

```
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=25)";
```

from various websites, but putting this in does not work either - the arrow icons are ugly again.

The icon itself (distributed with Tapestry) just seems to be a regular PNG, but I'm not an expert on image formats, so maybe there's a problem there?

Anyone else had this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure, but could be that -ms-filter needs to be in the correct order and also have the other properties (like the hasLayout hack) set:

try this:

```
DIV.t-palette-controls BUTTON[disabled] IMG {
    opacity:0.25; /* firefox, opera, safari, chrome */
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=25)"; /* IE 8 */
    filter:alpha(opacity=25); /* IE 4, 5, 6 and 7 */
    zoom:1 /* so the element "hasLayout"
    /* or, to trigger "hasLayout" set a width or height */
}
```

[Source and Explanation](http://www.itnewb.com/tutorial/Cross-Browser-CSS-Opacity-and-the-JavaScript-Fade-Fading-Effect)